# Google Docs Spreadsheet: get an individual row

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I'm using the [Java APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html) to update a Google Spreadsheet from a CSV file. I've created a method for deleting a row:

```
public void deleteRow(int row) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    URL listFeedUrl = _worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
    ListFeed feed = _service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
    List<ListEntry> entries = feed.getEntries();
    ListEntry entry = entries.get(row);
    entry.delete();
}
```

however, the problem is that I have to get ***all*** the entries to get the one entry I want. Is there a way that I can get one or even a smaller subset of the entries so I don't have to wait for the entire entry set to return to only delete one entry? (In its current state, this method takes a long time to run on large spreadsheets)

Comment: I ran into this need as well, but am using the protocol method.  While I don't have an answer for Java, see my answer here.  Maybe it will help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678331/retreive-a-range-of-rows-from-google-spreadsheet-using-list-based-feed-api-and

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#SendingStructuredRowQueries?