# How to send structured request to google sheets api?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-query-language

In the official googleapi library, the get method accepts only parameters in the form of "Data! A1: D4", where Data is the name of the sheet, A1: D4 is the selection range. But how to send a request for a selection, for example by cell value or by max / min value?

I know for sure that Google has a structured query language sq, which is similar to sql. I even found examples of such requests in the 2 and 3 versions of the library.

Comment: Tell us more about what type programming language you are using

Comment: @Martijn van Wezel , https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Comment: Also, see this thread.  I think it's utterly ridiculous that Google is removing the structured query method:  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/759

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question to yours a while ago, and figured out the answer.  However, I believe that Google will be deprecating the `sq` parameter feature after first quarter of 2020.  You will need to conform to method they use in API v4.

[Retrieve a range of rows from Google Spreadsheet using list-based feed API and "sq" parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678331/retrieve-a-range-of-rows-from-google-spreadsheet-using-list-based-feed-api-and)

Comment: I should add that this is another SO question I asked along similar lines.  It's baffling that Google would NOT include a method to query a spreadsheet document for a given value.  Seriously baffling.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463608/how-to-handle-structured-queries-for-retrieving-rows-with-google-sheets-api-v4